# Greedy Algorithm to return multiple optimal solutions

Tags: algorithms, optimization, scheduling, enumeration

How would one go about enumerating all the optimal answers for interval scheduling?

Not sure what to begin with, my guess is to use the other approaches i.e. earliest start time, shortest interval and fewest conflict in conjunction with the optimal implementation which is to use the earliest finish time approach.

Comment: Branch-and-bound algorithms are easy to extend to find all optimal solutions. There may be many, though. (Why do you have Greedy in the title?)